# paranoid check and verify checksum configuration for levelDB

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb

I have gone through http://activemq.apache.org/leveldb-store.html. 
What is paranoid check and difference between paranoid check and verify checksum ? What is the overhead of enabling these configuration ?

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: Really confuse between both the parameters. Can someone help me here ? @Hiram

Comment: Have you asked google?